# Template Parameter in C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, parameters, constructor

```
  template <class Object>
        class ListNode
        {   
            ListNode( const Object & theElement = Object( ), ListNode * n = NULL )
              : element( theElement ), next( n ) { }

            Object   element;
            ListNode *next;

            friend class List<Object>;
            friend class ListItr<Object>;
       };
```

Hi everyone, I am writing a program for my data structures class and I am supposed to use this .h header file included by my instructor. To my knowledge, Object is a template parameter. Can someone please explain why there are parentheses after Object in the ListNode constructor?

Thankyou!

Comment: Your ListNode constructor is the default constructor, that is, it acts like `ListNode::ListNode()`. So it default-initialize all members of its class: in your case `next` to nullptr, and `element` to its default value, that is the value of its default constructor, which is `Object::Object()`

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, it is a call to the default constructor of the `Object` class which was provided as a template parameter. This default constructed object is used as the default argument value for the first parameter of the `ListNode` constructor.

That's actually a lie, but it's simple to understand and covers most cases, so I put it at the top. In reality, it is a [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) of an object of type `Object`. In the case that `Object` is a class with user defined constructors, value initialization is a call to the default constructor. In the case that `Object` is a class without user defined constructors, value initialization is (recursively) defined as value initialization of all the members. And finally, in the case of primitives (int, double, pointers, etc...), value initialization is initialization to zero.

Answer (score 0):

It means, that if you create your `ListNode` object without parameters parameters, `theElement` parameter will be created automatically, using `Object` type default constructor.